# Summing the same number of cells in one row which are populated in another

Tags: excel-formula

I'm wanting to automatically count and sum the same number of cells in one row based on those which are populated in another. What is the formula?

For example, I have a pre-populated budget for a company for each month for 12 months. Each month I want to compare the cumulative actuals against the budget. 
I have 3 months (3 cells) worth of actuals which can be summed. What formula would I use to make a comparison and only sum the equivalent 3 cells in the budget row? And how do I then ensure that when there are only 4 months of data in one row, the corresponding 4 months in another are compared, and so on?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMIF` function to sum one range if the other is populated, e.g

`=SUMIF(D4:O4,"<>",D3:O3)`

"<>" means "not blank" so this sums `D3:O`3 only when the corresponding cell in `D4:O4` is not blank